# Making a JFrame resizable only "from the corner" in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Is there a simple way to make a jFrame resizeable but not horizontally/vertically-only? I want to be able to stretch it only from the corner

Comment: *"I want to be able to stretch it only from the corner"* So grab the corner. If you mean, you want to limit the **user** to only be able to resize it from the corner, please abandon making unusable / counter-intuitive GUIs.

Comment: If you want to maintain the aspect ratio of your JFrame, you're going to have to write the code yourself.  There is no simple way to do anything in Java Swing.